# scripting a set of scripts in OSX Tiger

Tags: userscripts

I have produced a set of calculating scripts, then I produced a script with these other scripts as a 'menu'.  This 'master script' runs whatever script the user has selected from the menu of scripts.  This works OK in Linux where the bin directory of scripts is addable to the PATH.

I *cannot* do this in OSX. In OSX I can only make each script individually executable by the adding .command to the script name method.  **BUT NO ONE SCRIPT CAN RUN ANOTHER SCRIPT.**

Is there some simple solution to this without needing to get bogged down in Automators and the like?

Answer (score 1):

On OS X you can add scripts to the `$PATH` as well (e.g. system-wide via `/etc/paths.d`), and make them executable using `chmod +x filename`. Try doing in Terminal on OS X what you did on Linux, it'll probably work.

Comment: On my OSX 10.4 Tiger there's no paths.d in /etc. Even if I created one I doubt the OS would recognize it. Furthermore I don't know the form of entries in such a (legitimate) file.

Comment: @tonyp In such cases, it helps to specify early that you use an old, no longer current version of OS X. If you don't, others will just assume you use the most recent release.